# How to count from my new int value?

Tags: c#, types, count, int

I had to calculate the price of a certain amount of tickets for like a theme park. 
The prices and amount of tickets has to be given by the user, but this is not my problem.
My problem is that when the user enters 11 tickets he gets one free, the eleventh ticket, but when he enters more than eleven he still has to pay for the eleventh ticket. Can someone help me out?

Here's my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Write("Voer de prijs van de ticket in: ");
    int priceTicket = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Eent ticket kost €{0},-\n\n", priceTicket);
    Console.Write("Voer in hoeveel tickets u wilt (per 10 1 gratis): ");
    int amountTickets = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    int ticketsTotalPrice = amountTickets * priceTicket;
    if(ticketsTotalPrice % 11 == 0) 
    {
        ticketsTotalPrice -= priceTicket;
    }
    string ticketsTotalPriceStr = ticketsTotalPrice.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine("\n\nU heeft "+amountTickets +" tickets gekozen, dit kost " +ticketsTotalPriceStr);
}
```

Comment: So, if-and-only-if tickets == 11, user gets a free one? Or if tickets == 11, 22, 33, etc he gets 1, 2, 3, etc free tickets?

Comment: can you use English names. i dont understand `prijsTicket` and `aantalTickets` and `ticketsTotaalPrijs`

Comment: exactly, but I want to keep the code compact as possible!

Comment: It is very close to english ;) : `price of ticket`, `number of tickets`, `tickets total price`.

Comment: edited it anyways ;)

Comment: Use integer division: `int freeTickets = (int)(amountTickets / 11)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula for price is  `(total- (total/11))*TicketPrice`

`total/11` is count of free tickets.
`(total- (total/11))` is number of tickets that he should pay for
`(total- (total/11))*TicketPrice` is the total price he should pay

`int total=10` then 10 ticket should be count;
`int total=11` then 10 ticket should be count;
`int total=12` then 11 ticket should be count;
...
...
`int total=21` then 20 ticket should be count;
`int total=22` then 20 ticket should be count;
`int total=23` then 21 ticket should be count;

Comment: You sir, are a genius ;) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

`ticketsTotaalPrijs % 11 == 0` only accounts for the cases, when the user buys a multiple of 11 tickets, i.e., 11, 22, 33, ...
In these cases you reduce the amount by exactly one ticket price, so only 10, 21, 32, ...
You need tou rethink this part. Since it is a homework, I won't go into details, since this is, what you should try to find out.

If I don't know further, I start to enumerate the different cases, and then try to find a pattern. I guess it should look like this: Left orderted tickets, right tickets to pay:

1->1, 
2->2,
...
9->9,
10->10,
11->10,

12->11,
13->12,
...
20->19,
21->20,
22->20,

23->21,
24->22,
...
31->29,
32->30,
33->30,

34->31,
...

Well, Johnny Mopp took it away, integer division is the key. For every 11 bought tickets, you get 1 more free. So the free tickets are `numberOfTickets / 11`. But since you don't give partial tickets away, you need to round this amount down. Integer division does exactly this (at least for positive numbers, but don't want to confuse).

Comment: Yeah I've been sitting here for hours. I`ll learn it anyways. Please give me an example, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> My problem is that when the user enters 11 tickets he gets one free, the eleventh ticket, but when he enters more than eleven he still has to pay for the eleventh ticket.

Change it so that it only applies the discount when there are 11 tickets:

```
int ticketsTotalPrice = amountTickets * priceTicket; 

if (amountTickets == 11) {
    ticketsTotalPrice -= priceTicket;
}
```

**Alternatives**

In case you didn't mean what I think you meant, here are some alternative solutions.

If you want it so that every 11th ticket is free, then you can do this:

```
int ticketsTotalPrice = (amountTickets - amountTickets / 11) * priceTicket;
```

Or if you want it so that it only applies the discount when the number of tickets is divisible by 11, you can do this:

```
int ticketsTotalPrice = amountTickets * priceTicket;

if (amountTickets % 11 == 0) {
    ticketsTotalPrice -= amountTickets / 11 * priceTicket;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that we get a free ticket for every 10 tickets we buy (based on this part of the code: **per 10 1 gratis**). So if we buy 10 tickets, we get 11. If we buy 11, we get 12. If we buy 20, we get 22.

This is wrong:

```
if(ticketsTotalPrice % 11 == 0)
```

Even if we simplify this scenario to the maximum and give away a free eleventh ticket, this will still not work. We'll get a free ticket when we buy 11 of them!

What you need to do is count the price for all the tickets that the costumer bought and then check how many multiples of ten of tickets (without the remainder) he bought. Then subtract the correct amount from the total. That way when he buys, for example, 44 tickets, he'll pay for 44 - 4 = 40 tickets.

Answer (score 0):

> when the user enters 11 tickets he gets one free, the eleventh ticket,

Its better to give user 1 free ticket for each 10 tickets. so if user enters 10 will get 11. if enters 11 will get 12 etc...

```
    int freeTickets = amountTickets / 10; //<< will give 1 free ticket for each 10 tickets
    int ticketsTotalPrice = (amountTickets + freeTickets) * priceTicket;
```

you can divide amount of tickets by `11` if you want to give free ticket for each `11`.

Answer (score 0):

Easy to loop through each:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Write("Voer de prijs van de ticket in: ");
    int priceTicket = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Eent ticket kost €{0},-\n\n", priceTicket);
    Console.Write("Voer in hoeveel tickets u wilt (per 10 1 gratis): ");
    int amountTickets = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    int ticketsTotalPrice = 0; //amountTickets * priceTicket;
    //if(ticketsTotalPrice % 11 == 0) 
    //{
    //    ticketsTotalPrice -= priceTicket;
    //}
    for(int i = 1; i <= amountTickets; i++)
    {
        if(i % 11 != 0)
        {
            ticketsTotalPrice += priceTicket;
        }
    }
    string ticketsTotalPriceStr = ticketsTotalPrice.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine("\n\nU heeft "+amountTickets +" tickets gekozen, dit kost " +ticketsTotalPriceStr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The math in this case is more straight forward than using a loop.  I recommend finding ticketTotalPrice inline.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Write("Voer de prijs van de ticket in: ");
    int priceTicket = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Eent ticket kost €{0},-\n\n", priceTicket);
    Console.Write("Voer in hoeveel tickets u wilt (per 10 1 gratis): ");
    int amountTickets = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    int ticketsTotalPrice = amountTickets * priceTicket - 
        (amountTickets / 10 * priceTicket);

    string ticketsTotalPriceStr = ticketsTotalPrice.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine("\n\nU heeft "+amountTickets +" tickets gekozen, dit kost " +
         ticketsTotalPriceStr);
}
```